# Keras forward pass with dropout

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dropout

I am trying to use dropout to get [error estimates](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02142.pdf) for a neural network.

This involves running several forward passes of my network after training, with dropout activated. Dropout does not seem to be activated when calling model.predict() however. Can this be done in Keras or must i take my weights elsewhere?

Comment: For TF>=2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/56085099/10375049

Answer (score 1):

Stochastic forward passes (that use dropout during test-time) can be implemented using keras backend function. Assuming you have a trained neural network called `model`:

```
from keras import backend as K

nb_MC_samples = 100
MC_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [model.layers[-1].output])

learning_phase = True  # use dropout at test time
MC_samples = [MC_output([x_test, learning_phase])[0] for _ in xrange(nb_MC_samples)]
MC_samples = np.array(MC_samples)  # [#samples x batch size x #classes]
```

For complete implementation see the following [ipython notebook](https://github.com/yaringal/acquisition_example/blob/master/acquisition_example.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

It is already done in Keras, see e.g. [this discussion](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5357) on the project's page. More on how it works can be found for instance in [CS231n: Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/) - AFAIK a very similar implementation is in Keras. Specifically:

> (...) Crucially, note that in the predict function we are not dropping
>   anymore, but we are performing a scaling of both hidden layer outputs
>   by pp. This is important because at test time all neurons see all
>   their inputs, so we want the outputs of neurons at test time to be
>   identical to their expected outputs at training time.

Comment: I need to do stochastic forward passes when getting error estimates. I.e. Run 100 forward passes with different dropout masks every time. But during predict it seems like no neurons are dropped

Comment: Sure, that's exactly what the code says here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L110 - in the test / prediction phase, dropout is not used. Instead, proportional weights are applied. If you'd like to have explicit Dropout in both directions, you could define your own version with Lambda.

Comment: He wants explicit Dropout in both directions, that is, he wants to be able to apply dropout in test time, not use proportional weights.